# How to turn on/off native log cat in ndk at runtime

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I use this snippet code to turn log on or off

```
   #define DEBUG 1

   #if DEBUG
   #include <android/log.h>
   #define  LOG_TAG    "native_log"
   #define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
   #else
   #  define  LOGD(...)  do {} while (0) // do nothing
   #endif

   // use it
   LOGD("%s : %d","value", val);
```

It worked fine by turn `DEBUG` flag on/off. The problem is I want to do it at run time in java side. What I want like this:

```
   // java 
   private native void nativeSetDebug(boolean flag);

   // jni
   JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_my_package_Native_nativeSetDebug(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jboolean flag){
        // what should I do in this method?
   }
```

Since the macros in c++ are replaced by the preprocessor by their value before source file even compiles, so I'm looking for another approach. Is there any ideas?

Comment: Use a function instead of a macro.  Or use a multi-line macro with an if statement in it, and have the jni function set the value of a boolean variable.

Comment: @GabeSechan could you post an example in answer? Because I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

macro file

```
extern bool useDebug;
#include <android/log.h>
#define  LOG_TAG    "native_log"
#define  LOGD(...)  if(useDebug){__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)}
```

C file

```
bool useDebug = true;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_my_package_Native_nativeSetDebug(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jboolean flag){
    useDebug = flag;
```

}

The extern is important, otherwise each file including the header will define its own variable and they won't be set correctly.